# How to mock Push notification native module in React native jest tests?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mocking, apple-push-notifications, jestjs

When using the module `react-native-push-notification`, I had this error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/index.android.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.

      at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:44:15)
      at new NativeEventEmitter (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:32:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/PushNotificationIOS.js:18:29)
      at Object.get PushNotificationIOS [as PushNotificationIOS] (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:97:34)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-push-notification/component/index.ios.js:10:23)
```

I tried to mock the module by creating `__mocks__/react-native.js` and putting this code within it:

```
const rn = require('react-native')

jest.mock('PushNotificationIOS', () => ({
  addEventListener: jest.fn(),
  requestPermissions: jest.fn(),
  then: jest.fn()
}));

module.exports = rn
```

Now, I have this error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/index.android.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null

      at Object.<anonymous>.Notifications.popInitialNotification (node_modules/react-native-push-notification/index.js:278:42)
      at Object.<anonymous>.Notifications.configure (node_modules/react-native-push-notification/index.js:93:6)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/utils/localPushNotification.js:4:39)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/actions/trip.js:5:28)
```

How I could mock fully this module the right way?

Comment: Why you don't mock `react-native-push-notification`.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I was looking for the way to mocking it, I already did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I mocked the module `PushNotificationIOS` by creating a setup file `jest/setup.js`:

```
jest.mock('PushNotificationIOS', () => {
  return {
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    requestPermissions: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    getInitialNotification: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  }
});
```

I've configured jest to run this setup file by adding this line into `packages.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    ...
    "setupFiles": ["./jest/setup.js"],
  }
```

Comment: change `PushNotificationIOS` to `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios` and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the line where the error is thrown, the lib tries to call `getInitialNotification` in the react-native module and expect an promise with some kind of result to be return. So you need to add this function to the mock and let it return a resolved promise.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I resolved by mocking `PushNotificationIOS`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly put `react-native-push-notification-ios` in `tranformIgnorePatterns`.

[image]