# Trying to mock just certain named exports (e.g. PushNotificationsIOS) in react-native with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

Given I have an implementations files that looks something :

```
import ReactNative, { PushNotificationIOS, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export function tryNotify() {
  PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('register', token => {
    callback(token);  
  });
  PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions();
}

export function trySave(token) {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('blah', token);
}
```

So if I want to write a test that spies on:

- `PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener`.

However, I can't work out how to mock it, because as soon as I mock `react-native`...

```
describe('notify()', () => {
  let generator;
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
      PushNotificationIOS: {
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        requestPermission: jest.fn(),
      },
    }));
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.unmock('react-native');
  });
  // No tests yet!
});
```

...I start getting the following error in my test:

```
Invariant Violation: Navigator is deprecated and has been removed from this package. It can now be installed and imported from `react-native-deprecated-custom-components` instead of `react-native`. Learn about alternative navigation solutions at http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html
```

My *best guess* is I'm interfering with the *inbuilt react-native mocks that jest provides*:

> The Jest preset built into react-native comes with a few defaults mocks that are applied on a react-native repository.
>
> [-jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#mock-native-modules-using-jestmock)

But I don't know where to look for to confirm this.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks!

## Edit

So I have two solutions:

- `AsyncStorage`: the answer below works, as does this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157979/how-to-mock-push-notification-native-module-in-react-native-jest-tests/43162085#43162085)
- `PushNotificationsIOS`: the answer below does not work for me, but this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157979/how-to-mock-push-notification-native-module-in-react-native-jest-tests/43162085#43162085) did

Comment: I know that the error is due to jest enumerating RN’s exports, and in doing so calling a getter that isn’t meant to be called (`import * as RN from 'react-native'` triggers the same error, nothing to do with jest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `jest.mock('react-native',...` because `react-native` does some [slightly nasty things](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.56.0/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js#L320) with its exports, such that they can't be imported en-masse by jest or anything else.

You'll need to bypass this by targeting the module more directly:

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS', () => {})
```

Comment: Its a step closer - this works with `AsyncStorage` but not with `PushNotificationsIOS`. It fails to find the module. Sidenote:  I use the options to set virtual to true to get rid of the error (`jest.mock(path, fn, { virtual: true})`), but this seems to break mocking in general.

Comment: Strangely, this works for `PushNotificationsIOS` https://stackoverflow.com/a/43162085/225813